# Checkbox & indeterminate

Tags: javascript, html5

Я разбирался с одним примером, где зашло в тупик.

Вот мой рабочий код, где вылезла такая ошибка. Тыкал в разной последовательности и по разным чекбоксам. Если по трем шагам сделать нажатиям чекбокса:

1 -> 1.1.2 -> 1

Видно, что не снята галочка indeterminate

```js
// переменная, где массив с чекбоксами
let treeInterest = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".interest__check"));

// функция поиска чекбокса
function searchCheckbox() {
  // цикл, где перебираем все чекбоксы
  for (let i = 0; i < treeInterest.length; i++) {
    // вешаем событие на клик изменения чекбокса
    treeInterest[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
      // переменная на дочерние чекбоксы, где ищет ближайший родительский элемент
      let childCheckbox = treeInterest[i]
        .closest(".interest")
        .querySelectorAll(".interests_active .interest__check");
      // условие, если поставить все галочки выведет все иначе снимутся все
      treeInterest[i].checked ?
        childCheckbox.forEach((elem) => (elem.checked = true)) :
        childCheckbox.forEach((elem) => (elem.checked = false));
      // поиск ближайшего элемента родителя
      let parentActive = treeInterest[i].closest(".interests_active");
      // проверка если есть родитель то изменяем чекбоксы через функцию
      if (parentActive) {
        changeTreeInterest(parentActive);
        // поиск родителя
        let parentActiveFarther = parentActive
          .closest(".interest")
          .querySelector(".interest__check")
          .closest(".interests_active");
        // если родитель есть то изменяем чекбоксы через функцию
        if (parentActiveFarther) {
          changeTreeInterest(parentActiveFarther);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
// функция изменения чекбоксов родителя
function changeTreeInterest(parentActive) {
  // переменные родителей чекбокса
  let parentInterest = parentActive.closest(".interest");
  let parent = parentInterest.querySelector(".interest__check");
  // переменная где массив соседних чекбоксов
  let neighborCheckbox = Array.from(
    parentActive.querySelectorAll(".interest__check")
  );
  // массив для значений чекбокса
  let childBooleanArray = [];
  // перебираем все соседние чекбоксы и пушим в новый массив
  neighborCheckbox.forEach((el) => childBooleanArray.push(el.checked));
  // переменная истина, если все элементы в массиве истины
  let childrenTrue = childBooleanArray.includes(true);
  // переменная ложь, если все элементы в массиве ложны
  let childrenFalse = childBooleanArray.includes(false);
  // если все галочки ложь, то убираем тире у родителя и галочку у родителя
  // если все галочки истина, то убираем тире у родителя и ставим галочку у родителя
  // если галочки и истина и ложь, то ставим тире родителю и ставим галочку родителю
  if (!childrenTrue && childrenFalse) {
    parent.indeterminate = false;
    parent.checked = false;
  } else if (childrenTrue && !childrenFalse) {
    parent.indeterminate = false;
    parent.checked = true;
  } else {
    parent.indeterminate = true;
    parent.checked = true;
  }
}
// вызов функции
searchCheckbox();
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="interests interests_main">
    <ul>
      <li class="interest">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1 </label>
        <ul class="interests interests_active">
          <li class="interest">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.1 </label>
            <!-- Задание повышенной сложности. Раскомментируйте код -->
            <ul class="interests interests_active">
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.1.1 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.1.2 </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="interest">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.2 </label>
            <ul class="interests interests_active">
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.2.1 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.2.2 </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="interest">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3 </label>
            <ul class="interests interests_active">
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3.1 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3.2 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3.3 </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотри, я обновил свой вариант. Сделал "обратный проход" по коллекции. Это позволяет учитывать вложения элементов.

Answer (score 1):

> вылезла такая ошибка

Мне твой вариант кода не особо понравился... Предложу свой вариант алгоритма.

```js
const oc = document.querySelector('.interests.interests_main')
oc.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (o.type != 'checkbox') return
  const v = o.checked
  o.closest('.interest').querySelectorAll('ul .interest__check').forEach(o => {
    o.checked = v
  })
  const oa = [...oc.querySelectorAll('.interest__check')]
  oa.reverse().forEach(o => {
    const op = o.closest('.interest').querySelector('ul')
    if (!op) return
    const n = op.querySelectorAll('.interest__check').length
    const m = op.querySelectorAll(':checked').length
    if (n === m) {
      o.checked = true
      o.indeterminate = false
      return
    }
    if (!m) {
      o.checked = false
      o.indeterminate = false
      return
    }
    o.indeterminate = true
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="interests interests_main">
    <ul>
      <li class="interest">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1 </label>
        <ul class="interests interests_active">
          <li class="interest">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.1 </label>
            <!-- Задание повышенной сложности. Раскомментируйте код -->
            <ul class="interests interests_active">
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.1.1 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.1.2 </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="interest">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.2 </label>
            <ul class="interests interests_active">
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.2.1 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.2.2 </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="interest">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3 </label>
            <ul class="interests interests_active">
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3.1 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3.2 </label>
              </li>
              <li class="interest">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" class="interest__check" />1.3.3 </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```